# Django charting with Chartit (highcharts wrapper)

Tags: django, highcharts, django-views

For a django project I'm trying to graph ratings/years of all the movies an actor has been in. I'm using Django-chartit to chart the graphs since it's just a wrapper for highcharts. I'm wondering if there is a way to make it so when you mouse over a point in the graph, it displays more detail. Right now it only displays the x/y info, which is the year/rating, but I also want it to display a lot more detail, such as the name of the film. The film model contains a lot of detail that I want to include, but I don't see how to do that in the documentation of Chartit.

This is what my view code looks like:

```
def film_chart_view(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        # grab the first person on the list
        person_search = Person.objects.filter(short = q)[0]
    #Step 1: Create a DataPool with the data we want to retrieve.
        filmdata = \
            DataPool(
               series=
                [{'options': {
                   'source': person_search.film_set.all()},
                  'terms': [
                    'year', 'rating', 'name']}
                 ])

        #Step 2: Create the Chart object
        cht = Chart(
                datasource = filmdata,
                series_options =
                  [{'options':{
                      'type': 'line',
                      'stacking': False},
                    'terms':{
                      'year': [
                        'rating',]
                      }}],
                chart_options =
                  {'title': {
                       'text': 'Ratings'},
                   'xAxis': {
                        'title': {
                           'text': 'Year'}}})

        #Step 3: Send the chart object to the template.
        return render_to_response('home/search_results.html',{'filmchart': cht})
```

I basically want more information to pop up when you mouse over a point on the graph.

I'm wondering if this is possible in chartit or would I have to abandon it and work directly with highcharts?

Comment: Did you finally find out any way to add info to those pop ups within chartit?